# Implicit assumptions in proofs of statements about limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

I was recently writing out a proof that a certain real valued function is continuous, and something bothered me along the way.

Suppose we have a function $f: D \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and we want to prove that $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L.$$

In order to do so we show that for all positive real $\epsilon$, there exists a positive real $\delta$ such that for all $x \in D$ such that $0< |x-a| < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$.

Suppose we are confident that  <strike>we have found such a $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\delta}$ for which the above holds for any $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\epsilon > 0}$</strike>  given any $\epsilon >0$, we can find a $\delta$ such that the above holds and want to prove the statement using it.

We let $\epsilon >0$, and define our $\delta$.

Then, we let $x \in D$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$. But hold on, how do we know that such an $x$ exists? Have we implicitly assumed that such an $x$ exists, and do not consider the case where one doesn't exist, since the statement "for all $x \in D$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$" would be vacuously true?

I'm confident that it can be proved that such an $x$ would exist (although I'm not sure  exactly how), but I am pretty sure that it is not necessary to include such proofs when proving statements about limits.

My main question is: is it okay to assume the existence of a real number in the domain of $f$ such that $|x-a| < \delta$, and if so, why?

Comment: To be precise, we have to state in the def mthat the function $f$ is defined in a [*neighborhood* of the point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)#Neighbourhood_of_a_point) $a$.

Comment: See [Limit of a function (at a point)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#More_general_subsets).

Comment: If $a$ is an isolated point of the domain, then $|x-a|<\delta$ is satisfied only by $x=a$ (for all sufficiently small $\delta>0$). But it causes no problem in proving continuity.

Comment: "Suppose we are confident that we have found such a $\delta$ for which the above holds for any $\epsilon>0$, and want to prove the statement using it. " I'm sure you can yourself realize what's wrong with that statement.

Comment: @broncoAbierto I am referring to the experimental stage before properly writing out the proof where one has decided on a $\delta$ to try to prove the statement, what's wrong with that?

Comment: @E-mu In general, you cannot find a $\delta$ such that the above holds for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: @E-mu Note, however, that if $f$ is continuous, for any $\epsilon>0$ you *can* find a $\delta$ such that the above holds.

Comment: @broncoAbierto The wording of that part of the question could be better. I did not mean that we know such a $\delta$ exists and now we're going to prove it, I meant that we have found a candidate $\delta$ through experimentation or other means which may lead to a proof that one does. Sorry about that.

Comment: @E-mu: It isn't a question of wording. The only way we can find a $\delta$ such that "the above holds for any $\epsilon$" is if $f$ is a constant function. Does that make sense, now? If not, I can elaborate.

Comment: Slight correction: I should have said that $f$ is constant in an interval about $a.$

Comment: Oh, I think I see now! I should have said something like: "Suppose we are confident that given any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find a $\delta$ such that the above holds", right? We can't always find a $\delta$  which covers all epsilons.

Comment: @E-mu You got it. Remember that in mathematics, what might look like "bad wording" can turn a true statement into a false one.

Comment: Definitely, thank you both for pointing that out. This is a very important lesson.

Comment: For continuity you don't need $0<|x-a|<\delta$ rather we just need $|x-a|<\delta$ so that a function defined at an isolated point is trivially continuous at that point.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Is it true that we cannot apply the definition with $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ to functions defined at isolated points, since $f(x)$ would have no meaning?

Comment: Yes! On the other hand the definition of limit necessarily requires $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the definition of the functional limit at a point $x=a$ necessitates that $f(x)$ has the definition over some one deleted neighborhood of $x=a$，which is a premise. Of course, in some more advanced calculus courses, $x=a$ may be the **accumulating point**.